# Buffered Image is generating empty images

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, java-io

I'm trying to read a file from system and then converting it to PNG and renaming it. I'm not sure why my following code is generating empty images:

```
public boolean processImage(File imageToProcess, String newName, String temp_location, String boxLocation) throws MagickException {
    File renamedImage = renameImage(newName, temp_location);
    boolean isProcessed = convertToPNG(imageToProcess, renamedImage);
    String filePath = renamedImage.getPath();
    return isProcessed;
}

private File renameImage(String newName, String temp_location) {
    File file = new File(temp_location + newName + "." + "png");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}

private boolean convertToPNG(File imageToConvert, File newImage) throws MagickException {
    boolean isProcessed = false;
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageToConvert);
        isProcessed = ImageIO.write(img, "png", newImage);
    } catch (IOException ioExec) {
        log.error("File not found: " + imageToConvert == null ? "Image is null" : imageToConvert);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgExec) {
        log.error("Image cannot be converted to PNG: " + imageToConvert == null ? "Image is null" : imageToConvert);
    }
    return isProcessed;
}
```

I have checked and verfied the images ImageIO.read is trying to read are present in the drive.

Comment: So I ran your code without issue, which makes the issue somewhere else, maybe the source image is blank. `file.createNewFile();` seems a bit pointless, but that's me

Comment: Looks like the same code worked on another VM. We have multiple servers set up with the same configuration. This code worked on one but didn't work on another. Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: No idea, I'd say it's an issue with the VM

Comment: `file.createNewFile()` will create an empty file at the temp location, regardless of whether there was an image in the original location, or if the image can be converted. Even if that's not the problem, taking @MadProgrammer's advice and remove that code will aid in debugging and find the real problem. What is the value of `isProcessed` when the images are not converted?